# SVN Code merging between multiple branches problems

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, svn-reintegrate, svn-merge-reintegrate

We use SVN 1.6
We like to perform code merging between branches and we are in a dilemma situation.

> Branch A exists
>   Folks making code changes on Branch A
>   Branch B created from branch A
>   Folks making code changes on both branches A and B
>   Branch A sync code merging to Branch B
>   After some time
>   Branch C created from branch A
>   Branch A continues sync code merging to Branch B (for a short time)
>   Folks making code changes on Branch C
>   Folks stop code changes on Branch A and branch "frozen", no more ci
>   Folks making code changes on Branch B
>   Branch C sync code merging to Branch B
>   Folks making code changes on Branches B and C
>   After some long period of time
>
> > Now Dilemma: We like to merge Branch B to Branch C

Because Branch B is from Branch A and not Branch C, we could not apply --reintegrate option for code merging from B to C because they don't share common ancestry

What's the least risky way to merge (without the --reintegrate option) to prevent "double merges/duplicated code" of (C in B) into branch C ?

Comment: Can you use "merge a range of revisions". Tortoise provides such a option, but I'm not sure if SVN 1.6 can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize your branch structure by a simple drawing. My understanding of your problem is:

```
               C ---- C ---- C ----- C
              /        \      \
A --- A ---- A --- A    \      \      ???
 \     \      \     \    \      \
  B --- B ---- B --- B -- B ---- B ---- B
```

I would integrate C and B in A. If that is not an option you could do it in 3 steps / 3 series of steps:

1. Merge all changes done in B into C but not those merged from A. Do this until you reach the last merge from A to B (which is not in C)
2. Merge this last merge from A to B also into C
3. Merge the remaining changes made on B (after the last merge from A), but leave out the changes included from C

I am not completely clear about your structure. If it would be

```
               C ---- C ---- C ----- C
              /        \      \
A --- A ---- A --- A    \      \      ???
 \     \            \    \      \
  B --- B ---- B --- B -- B ---- B ---- B
```

I would take the last changes from A directly into C.

Comment: Hi BHF, thanks for responding. You diagram looks correct in my text description. So from your solution, without using --reintegrate option, that we should merge rev numbers one at a time depending on 1 of 3 steps above; is that our correct understanding ?

Comment: You can do the steps as [merge a range of revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.advancedsyntax) or as [cherrypicking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) of individual change sets. You reduce the risk of doing things twice, if you commit step 1 before starting step 2. Just give it a try, if it goes wrong revert your working copy and start again. Good luck.